# R workspace doesn't load anything in Visual Studio Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, rstudio

[image]

I'm new to R and currently using vscode for it. i wanted it to show environment and plot like in RStudio, but the workspace just stayed empty after i ran the code. Is there some settings needs to be changed or packages to be install to solve this?

I followed the setting up instructions on vscode website and installed package 'languageserver' and 'httpgd', package 'radian' was said to not available for my version of R (4.3.1)

i expected it to show environment and plot like in RStudio.

[image]

Comment: `radian` is not an R package distributed through CRAN. It's an R console written in Python and usually installed through `conda` or `pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you ran the whole file in a `bash` terminal and got only the printed output. Instead, try adding a new `R` terminal and then running the code - use `CTRL + SHIFT + P` and then select "R: create terminal". You could also run each line of an R file using `CTRL + ENTER` - this will automatically create an R terminal and run the line of code corresponding to your cursor.

If you run code as described here, the plots will show up similarly to RStudio. You can view the variables in your environment with the [workspace viewer](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/Sidebar-user-interface#workspace-viewer) that is part of the VSCode R extension (thanks @margusl for this addition).

Comment: Workspace viewer is part of vscode R extension- https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/Sidebar-user-interface#workspace-viewer